# Understand frequency parameter while converting xts to ts object in R

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo

What is the meaning of frequency below; when I have converted my xts object to ts object and tried printing ts object I got below information.
My data is hourly data. But I could not understand how this below frequency is calculated. I want to make sure my ts object is treating my data as hourly data.

```
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 15548401 
Frequency = 0.000277777777777778 (how this is equivalent to hourly frequency?)
```

So, My dataframe looks like below intitally:

```
                   y
1484337600  19.22819            
1484341200  19.28906            
1484344800  19.28228            
1484348400  19.21669            
1484352000  19.32759            
1484355600  19.21833            
1484359200  19.20626            
1484362800  19.28737            
1484366400  19.20651            
1484370000  19.18424
```

It has epoch times and values. Epoch times are row.names in this dataframe.

Now, I converted into xts object using --

```
xts_dataframe <- xts(x = dataframe$y,
  order.by = as.POSIXct(as.numeric(row.names(dataframe)), origin="1970-01-01")) 

ts_dataframe <- as.ts(xts_dataframe)
```

Please suggest what I'm doing wrong? Basically I want to convert my initial dataframe to `ts()` object as I need to apply ARIMA on it. This data is per hour data. I'm really facing hard time to work with it.

Comment: Could you post both how you created your `xts` object and how you converted it to `ts`? What you have there is not an hourly frequency.

Comment: @ChrisHaug Please check the edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `frequency` is equivalent to `1/deltat`, where `deltat` is the fraction of the sampling period between successive observations.  `?frequency` gives the example that `deltat` would be "1/12 for monthly data".

In the case of hourly data, `deltat` is 3600, since there are 3600 seconds in an hour.  Since `frequency = 1 / deltat`, that means `frequency = 1 / 3600`, or `0.0002777778`.